# Ensure unique value (ID) in Excel from many users

Tags: vba, excel

I have many users, creating documents in Excel, working in many different workstations (in one company).
I need to ensure unique ID number for each document created.

The only solution I came up is to create shared Excel file with prepared unique ID in column A, and Status (Free/In Use) in Column B, and every time user needs ID, he uses macro to search first Free status in column B, take value from column A, and set status to In Use.
I do not like this solution - are there any more stable and reliable ideas?

Comment: A [UUID/GUID (Universally unique identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) could be an approach to generate unique IDs without a need to document them in a list and no need to lookup for free unique IDs.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this unique ID must be exactly 6 digits lenght. (I expect about 50-100 documents created every day. So I expect it to raise by 1 from 000001 to 999999

Comment: 6 digits is not much. You will need a global system accessible to every user that gives out the next valid free ID (Excel is not suitable for this approach you will just end up fiddling around, without having a solid and reliable solution).

Comment: For now 1 person is gathering all docs, printing it and making a stamp (phisically). Stamp increases by 1 every time it's "stamped". I'm looking for idea to avoid printing and making stamps digitally.

Answer (score 0):

Best case scenario for 6 digit uniquness, I can think of:

- Assign every user a specific number, depending on his username. Use Environ("Username") for this. Thus the first two digits are taken. Up to 100 users.
- For the next 4 digits, use the time it was created. Using `Now()`
- Hope that no user would create 2 files within one minute. Or make sure that the code runs more than a minute.
- Then speak with your bosses and ask for 6 digits more, to ensure uniqueness.
- Add day, month and year.

Or make a small DB with one table. In this table, you need one column with one value. Every user can access the value, then increment it automatically. It would work.

As a worst case and science fiction scenario, if you are not allowed to use a DB - use GoogleDocs. Make a new user, set a new password and make the incrementer of a the counter there. Then access it through the code. And increment it.

Comment: This could work with just using the last four digits as a counter.  It will allow each of the 100 (00-99) users to create 10,000 records. (000000 - 009999 to 990000 - 999999).  You'd have to store the number as text to allow for leading zeros.  My first thought was to use a database - no file sharing problems then, but I find there's always problems with getting management/IT Support to allow small databases (Access specifically)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Well, the database would work as a charm - it would take care of instant access and would queue the users appropriately. Concerning the leading zeroes - you store the numbers as INT, and if you get `23` you make it to `000023` in your code, the database is used as a counter.

Comment: I was thinking of the leading zeros in Excel.  In a database most of the problems magically disappear.... to be replaced by other ones.